# How to create a multi-dimensional Hashtable of COM (PDF) objects in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I currently have functioning code that creates and modifies Nuance PDF objects contained in a Hashtable, where the hashkey is the output stream (a string value). Unfortunately, when each PDF gets over 10 MB or so, merging additional PDFs into it slows the program to a crawl.

I'd like to add a dimension to my Hashtable using an additional integer index so I can simply open a fresh PDF whenever the number of merged documents exceeds a value from my config file.

When I initialize the nested Hashtable, all appears fine at first. I'm able to assign the Nuance PDF objects to it. However, when I attempt to access one of the PDF elements, TryCast fails (returns nothing).

Here's how I set up the first instance of OutStream1 (OutStream1 is just a hard-coded example for simplification - the actual output streams are read from the config file).

My goal is to continue adding new PDF objects to the inner Hashtable as needed when the threshold is reached.

```
Dim pdfOutput As Hashtable = New Hashtable
Dim outTemp As Hashtable = New Hashtable
outTemp(0) = CreateObject("NuancePDF.DDDoc")
pdfOutput("OutStream1") = outTemp(0)
```

When ready to manipulate the PDF object, the assignment to pdMrgDoc fails. Without using TryCast, the error message is:

*Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.*

```
Dim pdMrgStream As Hashtable = pdfOutput("OutStream1")
Dim pdMrgDoc As New Object
pdMrgDoc = pdMrgStream(0)
```

I'm not sure what that error message means. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use typed containers instead of the legacy untyped Hashtable.

I haven't tested this, but it ought to work as you intend:

```
Dim pdfOutput As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Integer, Object))
Dim entry as New Dictionary(Of Integer, Object)

entry.Add(0, CreateObject("NuancePDF.DDDoc"))
pdfOutput.Add("OutStream1", entry)
```

Then, the compiler will catch basic errors due to compile-time type errors, instead of waiting to fail until a cast fails at runtime.

You might also want to consider encapsulating the behavior in a class instead of storing a dictionary and managing the behavior outside.  It should result in cleaner, easier-to-maintain code.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm a little embarrassed to admit I tried using a dictionary before, but had my syntax wrong. Much appreciated...